# Increment value inside curly brackets

Tags: excel, increment, autofill, array-formulas

I am using a formula in Excel 2010 to display the individual with the most wins, as below:

```
IF($P$3="Most wins",SUM(LARGE(Wins,{1})),"FALSE")
```

where wins represents an array of an indefinite number of individuals.

However I would like to be able to autofill this, or similar, such that the next row displays the following:

```
IF($P$3="Most wins",SUM(LARGE(Wins,{2})),"FALSE")
```

Unfortunately I can't get the value inside the curly brackets to increment, which is causing no end off issues when the formula is going to be dragged down beyond 1,000 rows.

Is this possible, or am I using the wrong method?

Comment: If the formula is on row 3 (thought this due to the $P$3) how about replace `{1}` with `ROW()-2`.

Comment: `LARGE(Wins, {1})` returns the first largest value of the `Wins`array, and `LARGE(Wins, {2})` returns the second largest value in the `Wins` array, and I doubt this is not what you want, please clarify your question

Comment: I would use `Row(1:1)` in place of `{1}` then it does not matter in which row you start as it is dragged down it will increment.  To increment as you drag across use `Column(A:A)`

Comment: @ScottCraner What are you doing up so early?  Shouldn't you still be fixing your first coffee, or walking the dog?

Comment: @ScottCraner Your answer has achieved what I intended, thank you very much.

Comment: @ForwardEd just a quick note before I jet off to work.

Comment: @ScottCraner Dont answer SO and Drive!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=IF($P$3="Most wins",SUM(LARGE(Wins,ROW(A1))),"FALSE")
```

Place that in the top of your column and copy it down.  As you do, the cell reference for A1 will change from A1 to A2 to A3, etc.  The ROW function returns the number of the row of the cell reference.

Alternatively as pointed out in Darren's comment, you could also use ROW()-2 if you data is starting in the second row.  This has the advantage if you ver deleted the 1 row or column, you will not screw up your cell references.

Comment: I ended up using Scott's version, but both seem to work, thanks.